# Library command in R can't find packages

Tags: r, ggplot2, package, loading

Sucessfully installed ggplot2 and its dependencies . When tring to load it, I get this problem:

```
library(ggplot2)
Erro: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env):
 não foi possível abrir o arquivo 'C:/Users/TÃ©o/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/rlang/R/rlang.rdb': No such file or directory
```

rlang is actually installed. Uninstalled it and installed again. Sucessful installation:

```
package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Téo\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp61fgXb\downloaded_packages
```

Tried to load it. No sucess:

```
library(rlang)
Erro: package or namespace load failed for ‘rlang’ in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env):
não foi possível abrir o arquivo 'C:/Users/TÃ©o/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/rlang/R/rlang.rdb': No such file or directory`
```

Thing is, **some packages in the same directory can be loaded**. I can load UTF8 , for example, but not the others.

```
library(utf8)
> library(rstudioapi)
Erro: package or namespace load failed for ‘rstudioapi’ in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env):
 não foi possível abrir o arquivo 'C:/Users/TÃ©o/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/rstudioapi/R/rstudioapi.rdb': No such file or directory
```

What would be the problem here?

Comment: It helps sometimes to avoid accents and international characters in path names. As a workaround, you may consider to install packages in admin mode: open R directly with admin privileges and install packages to the system library.

Comment: I installed packages to the system library and it worked!  ``library(ggplot2, lib.loc = "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.0/library")`` . I will have to look into changing the username, maybe that's the main problem